# Trim file after a blank line

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, readline

I have a text file that has multiple blank lines and Im trying to return all the lines between two of them specifically

so if I have a file that looks like this:

```
 ____________________________
 1########################
 2##########################
 3
 4########################
 5##########################
 6#######################
 7
 8#########################
 9##########################
 10#######################
 11####################
 12########################
 13#########################
 14
 15##########################
 ----------------------------
```

I would like to grab lines 8-13. Unfortunately, it might not always be 8-13 as it could be 9-20 or 7-8, but it will however always be between the 2nd and 3rd line break.

I know how to trim characters and pull out singular lines, but I have no idea how to trim entire sections.

Any help would be appreciated, even if you just point me to a tutorial.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [tag:vb.net], [tag:vb] or [tag:vbscript]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was trimming the last part and searching for what I needed in the first part (I know I didnt include the searching part in the question, but I was just trying to figure out a way to narrow down the search results as it would have had repeated results). Im posting this incase anyone else stumbles upon this looking for some answers.

```
Dim applist() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\applist.txt")
Dim findICSName As String = "pid"
Dim ICSName As New Regex("\:.*?\(")
Dim x = 0
    Do Until applist(x).Contains("Total PSS by OOM adjustment:")
        If applist(x).Contains(findICSName) Then
            app = ICSName.Match(applist(x)).Value
            app = app.TrimStart(CChar(": "))
            app = app.TrimEnd(CChar("("))
            ListBox1.Items.Add(app)
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop
End If
```

How this works is that it looks through each line for the regex until it reaches first word in the breakpoint "Total PSS by OOM adjustment:"

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea here is to get the entire thing as a string, split it into groups at the double line breaks, and then reference the group you want (in your case, the third one).

```
Dim value As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt")

Dim breakString As String = Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine

Dim groups As String() = value.Split({breakString}, StringSplitOptions.None)

Dim desiredString As String = groups(2)

MsgBox(desiredString)
```

**Edit:**
In response to the question in your comment -

Environment.NewLine is a more dynamic way of specifying a line break. Assuming you're running on windows - you could use VbCrLf as well. The idea is that if you were to compile the same code on Linux, it Environment.NewLine would generate a Lf instead. You can see here for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

The reason I used `Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine` is because you want to break your information where there are two line breaks (one at the end of the last line of a paragraph, and one for the blank line before the next paragraph)

Comment: Other than the extraneous empty string concat (`& "" &` should just be `&`), a good answer.

Comment: Ah, you are right. That was in there while I was having problems with the string overload. Editing answer now. Thanks!

Comment: what does "Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine" mean?